# Как настроить webhook aiogram на сервере с установлеными vestacp apache+nginx?

Tags: python-3.x, nginx, apache, aiogram, webhook

Вот код бота, файл `bot.py` доступен по адресу `https://example.site/bot.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/evn python3

import logging
import requests
import asyncio
import ssl
import sys
from aiohttp import web


from aiogram import Bot, types
from aiogram.contrib.middlewares.logging import LoggingMiddleware
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from aiogram.dispatcher.webhook import get_new_configured_app
from aiogram.dispatcher.webhook import SendMessage
from aiogram.utils.executor import start_webhook

API_TOKEN = '00000000:AAAA'

WEBHOOK_HOST = """https://examole.site"""
WEBHOOK_PATH = """/bot.py"""
WEBHOOK_URL = f"{WEBHOOK_HOST}{WEBHOOK_PATH}"

WEBAPP_HOST ='serverip'
WEBAPP_PORT = 443

SSL_KEY = "./cert/CA.key"
SSL_PEM = "./cert/CA.pem"

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

bot = Bot(API_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)
dp.middleware.setup(LoggingMiddleware())


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def startcom(message: types.Message):
    if message.chat.type == "private":
        textmsg = "Привет.."
    else:
        textmsg = "Этот бот не предназначен для использования в общих чатах."
    return SendMessage(message.chat.id, text=textmsg)


async def on_startup():
    await bot.set_webhook(WEBHOOK_URL)

    webhook = await bot.get_webhook_info()
    if webhook.url != WEBHOOK_URL:
        if not webhook.url:
            await bot.delete_webhook()

        await bot.set_webhook(WEBHOOK_URL, certificate=open(SSL_PEM, 'rb'))


async def on_shutdown():
    logging.warning('Shutting down..')
    await bot.delete_webhook()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = get_new_configured_app(dispatcher=dp, path=WEBHOOK_PATH)
    app.on_startup.append(on_startup)
    app.on_shutdown.append(on_shutdown)

    context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
    context.load_cert_chain(SSL_PEM, SSL_KEY)

    web.run_app(app, host=WEBAPP_HOST, port=WEBAPP_PORT,ssl_context=context)
```

Вот это в .htaccess в папке где лежит `bot.py`

```
Options -Indexes +ExecCGI
AddHandler cgi-script .py
RewriteEngine On
```

На сервере установлена панель VestaCP apache+nginx .

Вебхук установил на `https://example.site/bot.py`. `bot.py` запускаю с терминала через ssh, но бот не получает обновления.

Я не силен в настройках apache, nginx, Подскажите как сделать что бы бот получал обновления?

Answer (score 0):

> Обратный прокси-сервер – это тип прокси-сервера, который ретранслирует HTTP/HTPPS-запросы на один или несколько бэкенд-серверов. Обратные прокси-серверы полезны, так как многие современные веб-приложения для обработки HTTP-запросов используют бэкенд-серверы приложений (к которым пользователи не должны иметь доступ напрямую), а также часто поддерживают только базовые функции HTTP.

После этих команд:

```
sudo a2enmod proxy
sudo a2enmod proxy_http
sudo a2enmod proxy_balancer
sudo a2enmod lbmethod_byrequests
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

и изменений в `bot.py`:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_webhook(dispatcher=dp,
                  webhook_path=WEBHOOK_PATH,
                  on_startup=on_startup,
                  on_shutdown=on_shutdown,
                  skip_updates=True,
                  host=WEBAPP_HOST,
                  port=WEBAPP_PORT)
```

Бот начал получать обновления.

Answer (score 0):

на nginx помогла запись proxy_pass в конфиг

```
location /path-to-webhook/ {
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3001;
}
```